# Finding Products within large Digits

Tags: javascript, loops, substring

I have been working on a way to find products of 5 digits within a large number.  For example, I have the number `158293846502992387489496092739449602783` And I want to take the first 5 digits (`1,5,8,2,9`) and multiply them, then the second, (`5,8,2,9,3`), multiply then, then the third... And so on.  Then I want to find the largest of all of them I find, now I came up with the following code to solve this problem:

```
// I put the digit into a string so I can modify certain parts.
var digit = "158293846502992387489496092739449602783";

var digitLength = digit.length;

var max = 0;

var tempHolder;

var tempDigit = 0;

var tempArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i<=digitLength; i++){
    tempHolder = digit.substring(i, i+5);
    tempArray = tempHolder.split("");

    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        tempDigit += tempArray[j];
    }

    if(tempDigit > max){
        max = tempDigit;
    }
}

console.log(max);
```

It logs to the console A longer number than what I put into it, along with 10 undefined, no spaces.  Can anyone figure out the problem here?

Comment: ?? There are no multiplications in that code at all.

Comment: So Sorry, the tempDigit += tempArray[j] should be a *= instead... sorry for the mistake.

Comment: This still does not help, as It only returns 0 now

Comment: You start "tempDigit" off at zero. What's zero times anything?  I think it should be reset to `1` at the top of the main loop, before each set of five digits.

Comment: I found that that does indeed work. Thanks for the help